# Menu on the taxonomy term page

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, navigation

maybe the solution to my problem is quite simple but I can not find a way on the taxonomy term page to show a menu block!

I use drupal 8 with bartik theme and have a menu based on taxonomic terms (Module: Taxonomy Menu + Menu Block). This menu is also always displayed everywhere (with the set content types). Just not on the taxonomy term page (the page where all entries are displayed from a taxonomy item in a teaser view).

if I look under Structure> Block Layout> Navigation> Configuration: is there "page" there I tried to enter URL of the taxonomy terms or also / * but both remains without effect.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post the Visibility settings for your block.

Comment: ok I have posted a few pictures

Comment: Because taxonomy terms are not content types, the visibility setting won’t match

Comment: If I got this right, you want the menu to be visible on _any_ page. In this case remove _all_ visibility settings, completely empty visibility setting means "visible everywhere".

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments if you want it shown everywhere you should untick the Type options, then they apply anyway. And on the `Seite` delete everything, that should show it everywhere too without restrictions (no need for `/*`).

But I think your particular configuration isn't working because you have included the `/de/` in your path under `Seite`, the language prefix is *not* part of the Drupal path. Remove it from there and it should work.

Instead of:

`/de/tutorial/erste-schritte`

it should say:

`/tutorial/erste-schritte`

You have the Visibility limited to the German language under the `Sprache` tab.